# Makefile recompiles after cleaning objects (but not the name target)

Tags: makefile

When I call the `clean` rule with `make clean` all objects are correctly deleted. However if just after I call the `all` rule with `make` it recompiles all the objects again, even if the target is already there.

As far as I know, it should not recompile the objects beacuse the `$(NAME)` dependecy in the `all` rule is already satisfied. Indeed `make clean` erase just the object and not the program target too.

Somebody can explain me how to avoid recompiling after a `make clean` call? Thank you.

Here is the makefile:

```
NAME = myprogram

CC = clang++
CFLAGS = -Werror -Wextra -Wall -O3 -std=c++11

DIR_SRCS = srcs/
DIR_OBJS = objs/
DIR_INCS = incs/

FILES = main.cpp \
        file1.cpp \
        files2.cpp \
        file3.cpp \

OBJS = $(addprefix $(DIR_OBJS), $(notdir $(addprefix $(DIR_SRCS), $(FILES:.cpp=.o))))

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) -I$(DIR_INCS) -o $(NAME)

$(DIR_OBJS)%.o: $(DIR_SRCS)%.cpp
    mkdir -p $(DIR_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(DIR_INCS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(DIR_OBJS)

fclean: clean 
    rm -f $(NAME)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$(NAME)` dependecy in the `all` rule is **NOT** satisfied, because `$(NAME)` depends on `$(OBJS)` - and `$(OBJS)` does not exist (after `make clean`). This is how `make` works. If any dependencies don't exists or are newer than the target - the dependecies need to be regenerated (and in turn - the target).

For example: `program` --> `program.o` --> `(program.c, program.h)`

If `program.c` or `program.h` is newer than `program.o` : `program.o` needs to be regenerated (updated). This causes `program.o` to be newer than `program` - `program` needs to be relinked (using `program.o`).